# Including a custom font file in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, fonts

Is it possible to include a custom font, file and all inside a Wordpress plugin?

Say the plugin directory is wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/
So I add in the font, into wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/fonts/font.ttf
Now how do I access that custom font inside the plugin's css file?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'my-font';  
  src: url(wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/fonts/my-font.ttf);  
  font-weight: normal;  
}
```

Doesn't seem to work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually plugin developers define a constants like `PLUGIN_DIR_PATH` and `PLUGIN_DIR_URL` with the current directory path and url respectively, where `PLUGIN` can be your plugin's name to make it unique. Say your plugin's name is **Example**

```
define( 'EXAMPLE_DIR_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'EXAMPLE_DIR_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
```

But in your case, we only need `EXAMPLE_DIR_URL`. Now, anywhere in your plugin, if you need to referense any resource, just use `EXAMPLE_DIR_URL` as your base. In your case,

```
@font-face {
  font-family: php'my-font';  
  src: url(<?= EXAMPLE_DIR_URL; ?>'/fonts/my-font.ttf);  
  font-weight: normal;  
}
```

Comment: Am I placing the @font-face into the .css file inside the plugin folder? If so, it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Output this to `wp_head` using an action.